# how to Insert data from PHP dropdown date into a Mysql database table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html

this is my form

```
<option value="">
<?php
$d=strtotime("today");

 $d=strtotime("-3 Months");
echo date("Y-m-d ", $d) . "<br>";
?>
</option>
```

[and it show like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crcwP.png)

Comment: Put the code in the question, not images of it, nobody is going to retype that by hand to debug it to help you out.

Comment: sorry, i will edit

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value for `<option>` tags of your dates to be able to insert them as well

```
<select name='ver_date'>
    <?php
      $d=strtotime("-3 Months");
      $date = date("Y-m-d ", $d);
    ?>

    <option value='<?php echo $date;?>'>
        <?php echo $date;?>
    </option>

    <?php
     $d=strtotime("today");
     $date = date("Y-m-d ", $d);
    ?>

    <option value='<?php echo $date;?>'>
        <?php echo $date;?>
    </option>

   <?php
     $d=strtotime("+3 Months");
     $date = date("Y-m-d ", $d);
    ?>

    <option value='<?php echo $date;?>'>
        <?php echo $date;?>
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: it notice undefined to me

Comment: I've altered the code example to match the new code you provided . Try this and let us know if it works. You will need to re declare the $date variable before every option tag to have the new value

Comment: if i want to +3 months what should i do?

Comment: it work if i upload today date but if i +3 month it will not insert

Comment: Before every <option> tag you will need to have a code that sets the value into the $date variable. So you would have <?php $d = strtotime("+3 Months"); $date = date("Y-m-d", $d); ?> and than the <option value="<?php echo $date;?>"><?php echo $date;?></option>      | Take a look at the expanded example code in my answer ...

Answer (score 0):

this is my php

```
<?php
$msg = "";
if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {

$target = "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ifcg/pdf/".basename($_FILES['p_file']['name']);

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'IFCG');
$upload = $_POST['upload'];
$p_file = $_FILES['p_file']['name'];
$policy_no = $_POST['policy_no'];
$ver_date = $_POST['ver_date'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO Product_ver (policy_no, p_file, ver_date) VALUES ( '$policy_no', '$p_file','$ver_date')";
mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['p_file']['tmp_name'], $target)){
    $msg = "Successfully";
}else{
    $msg = "Upload Failed";
}
}



?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be mindful with your code about vulnerabilities. See here: https://php.earth/docs/security/uploading

Answer (score 0):

this is my code for +3 months it not insert for me but if i choose today it will upload

```
<option value='<?php echo date("Y-m-d", $d);?>'>
<?php

$d=strtotime("+3 Months");
echo date("Y-m-d ", $d) . "<br>";



?>
</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code for HTML**

```
<select name="reg_date">
   <?php
   $d1=strtotime("today");
   $d2=strtotime("-3 Months");
   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $d1; ?>"><?php echo date("Y-m-d ", $d1); ?></option>
   <option value="<?php echo $d2; ?>"><?php echo date("Y-m-d ", $d2); ?></option>
</select>
```

***I am not using any loop because you have only 2 options. It's just for demo purpose.***

**And, Code for PHP, where you are handling the POST action.**

```
$reg_date = $_POST['reg_date];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_reg_info SET reg_date = '".$reg_date."');
```

**Here I am assuming your table field 'reg_date' is BIGINT and Length is 20. I am saving UNIXTimestamp because that is powerful you can do any manipulation with that.**

Comment: it come out like this 1528840800 in database mysql

Comment: it Convert dates to timestamps ,what should i do?

Comment: I know that's it's UNIXTimestamp. Now you can you it any where. now you can use <?php echo date("Y-m-d ", $reg_date_fetched_from_db); ?> later if client wants to change the for date format or you want to do some date operations/calculations you can easily do that with this UnixTimeStamp.